# How to use color in `caption` package?

Tags: color, captions

I am using `caption` package to customize captions in my thesis. My current code is:

```
\usepackage[width=0.6\textwidth ,font={small, sf,it},labelfont=bf,
labelsep=endash, format=plain,labelsep=period]{caption}
```

but I'd like to add color to caption label. Something like image below:
[Caption http://img24.ir/uploads/1365940937491.png](http://img24.ir/uploads/1365940937491.png)

Comment: Some feedback would be kind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation of caption provides such an example on page 25.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup{labelfont={blue,bf}}
```

As mentioned by Axel Sommerfeld the following will work too:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=blue,bf}}
```

Here a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[width=0.6\textwidth ,font={small, sf,it},labelfont={color=blue,bf},
labelsep=endash, format=plain,labelsep=period]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Eiffel Tower, Paris}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```